# Dynamic view changes (i.e. UILabel) with autoLayout

Tags: ios, dynamic, autolayout, sizetofit

I need to create two UILabels which should be resized dynamically based on text size inside `UITableViewCell`.
The first `UILabel` should **grow** (based on the text) to the left and always align 15 points to the right border. 
the second `UILabel` should (also grow dynamically to the left) and be aligned 7 points to the right of the first UILabel.

...      `[label 2]<--7p-->[label 1]<--15p-->|right cell border`

1. Can this be done only on the **storyBoard** (without code) ?
2. I defined a horizontal constraints in the storyboard layout and `sizeToFit:` on the code.
   and found out that the horizontal constraints were overridden.
   Tried to change frames in the `viewDidLoad:` but not all were updated (performing selector with 0 delay - update all labels in all of the cells but created a one second delay.)

Please advise,
Thanks Asaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1)

Actually you can do that in code. but I think Interface Builder better in your case.

I think you don't have to [sizeToFit:] in code.

if you don't set the width constraints to your labels, I think there is warning in your storyboard.

UIControls like UILabel, UIButton has intrinsic size because they have a text content. so you don't need to set the width constraint.

but you have a two labels and you should let autolayout knows which label is more important when there is conflict between labels. - ex. if labels have long text, which label's text are shown without shortening(...).

To do that, set the Hugging (or Compression) Priority in Interface Builder.

Question 2)

[viewDidLoad:] is not suitable for changing geometry things. View of UIViewController is added in view hierarchy after [viewWillAppear:]

if you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result either in code or with StoryBoard auto-layout. Here are the steps for Storyboard auto-layout:

**1.** Ensure that you have cell with two labels and no auto-layout constraints(clear them if any)

**2.** Add constraints to `Label 1`:

[image: TwoLabelsCell_Label1_Constraints]

**3.** Add constraints to `Label 2`:

[image: TwoLabelsCell_Label2_Constraints]

**Result:**

[image: TwoLabelsCell_Result]

**Remarks:**

- Manipulations with layout should be done by overriding `updateViewConstraints` in your view controller. Just do not forget to call `[super updateViewConstraints]`.
- No need to deal with `sizeToFit:` method in your case.

Comment: @Asaf Have you checked the solution? Does it solves your problem?